# How to get External Display work in Zenbook with Intel Graphics?

Tags: 16.04, display, laptop, intel-graphics

I bought a laptop ASUS Zenbook ux305ua. There is a micro HDMI port on this laptop. 
When I plug a HDMI-2-VGA adapter on laptop with Windows, it works as well, but ubuntu 16.04 cannot detect external monitor. Did I miss any driver?

I do `cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid` but I get nothing.
I go to "System Settings > Displays" and click "Detect Displays", but still not works.

Ubuntu: 16.04
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX305UA
GPU: Intel
Graphic package: `xserver-xorg-video-intel`

Comment: What is your external monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Your GPU is the integrated Intel which uses the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` by default. It is very buggy and will be removed from Ubuntu in the coming releases for `modesetting`. 
You can do

1. `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel`, which puts Ubuntu to use the `modesetting` package.
2. Reboot
3. Let me know your result.

   - If the result is unsuccessful, you can install the package back by `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`.

As a side-note, my laptop crashes often with `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package, just when I connect the cable there.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Ubuntu: 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.7
GPU: Intel integrated
Graphic package: `modesetting`

Comment: Did you mean "sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-lts-utopic" ?
After i remove xserver-xorg-video-intel and install modesetting (above package name).
My laptop still cannot detect external monitor.

Comment: After purging, you do not need install `modesetting`. The system will choose to use it automatically. Did you reboot?