# Ubuntu 16.04 External display detection doesn't work properly

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, asus

I use Asus UX305L with an external display Samsung SyncMasterF2380 connected via micro HDMI. Nevertheless, after a fresh Ubuntu install, from time to time, the following "strange" problems with an external display occur:

1. Ubuntu doesn't detect external monitor after system start. However,
   if I click on System Settings icon multiple times it does.
2. Ubuntu doesn't detect external monitor after system start and changes resolution of the laptop screen. After I click on System Settings icon multiple times it does detect an external display and changes the resolution of the laptop screen back.

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf**

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/monitors.conf**

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "HDMI1"
  Option "LeftOf" "Screen 0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Screen 0"
  Option "RightOf" "HDMI1"
EndSection
```

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/screen-resolution.conf**

```
Section "Screen"
  Identifier "HDMI1"
  SubSection "Display"
  Modes "1920x1080"
  EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen 0"
  SubSection "Display"
  Modes "1600x900"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**xrandr -q shows**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: I have the same issue with my Asus Zenbook and Ubuntu 18 occassionally. Sometimes the external monitor isn't found, sometimes it's found - same HDMI adapter, cable, monitor. Clicking system settings doesn't help for me though. Haven't identified a specific pattern, really just happens randomly at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

According to reports you cannot use `TearFree` and `xua` acceleration method at the same time. You need to use the acceleration method `sna` which is the default so you can simply delete that line in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel`.

More details can be found in Arch Linux documentation [intel_graphics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics)

Although I had some screen tearing a few months ago it went away on it's own after some Ubuntu kernel updates and it could be that option isn't required anymore on your system. The reason you would want to remove the option (if it's no longer required) is there are other conflicts that can occur as described in the link.

Comment: I have deleted that line but It doesn't seem to affect this issue. And I noticed another problem - on youtube all videos have an extremely slow sound.

Comment: Leave the line out going forward since it's not needed and does cause problems. I found another Asus user in AskUbuntu with external display not working with intel graphics you can read: [zenbook external display](http://askubuntu.com/questions/809448/how-to-get-external-display-work-in-zenbook-with-intel-graphics)

Comment: that didn't work out for me

Comment: I added the zenbook tag to your question in the hopes other users of your laptop might share experiences. Unfortunately I only own a Toshiba and Dell and not all laptop problems are universal.